# Connection to Oracle server

Tags: c#, oracle

It will be my first post on StackOverflow so forgive me for breaking any rules.

I am new to programming and my first task was to create an application that builds a query and runs it on an Oracle database. 
It was not easy but with great use of Google and this site I managed, although most of my code was copy/paste with modifications.

Unfortunately I can't get past one problem. The application is running on my PC smoothly but when I am trying to run it on any other it crashes. As far as I know the problem is that those computers don't have Oracle drivers installed. My question is:

Can I somehow bind necessary "drivers" to my application and not be forced to install Oracle drivers on every PC where the app will be used?

I know that question is wide, but sometimes I don't even know how to ask Google or answers are too complicated for me to understand.

I will be very happy for any directions or guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Oracle Instant Client** it does not require installation. You can find it here : [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html) .

Answer (score 0):

Try this link:
[DataBinding and ADO.NET in WPF](http://erkapeblog.blogspot.in/2010/05/data-binding-and-adonet-in-wpf.html)

Connection String: `SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));uid=myUsername;pwd=myPassword;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oracle Managed ODP.NET - available from nuget package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/

It will require only to copy `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` file with your application.